# How to synchronize shared resources with async/await pattern

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-4.5

I'm working on some software that is essentially a pub/sub framework.

On subscription, I have to keep a record of what is being subscribed to, and I need to make both subscription and unsubscription atomic operations. A connection is identified by a guid, and can have multiple subscriptions (Alice wants NEWS and WEATHER, for example). So once Alice establishes a connection with an ID, she can `Subscribe()` multiple times to events she cares about.

In simple terms, my subscribe looks like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _subscriptionsForConnection;
async Task Subscribe()
{
   List<string> subscriptikons = _subscriptionsForConnection.GetOrAdd(connectionId, MakeNewList);
   await underlyingComponentA.SubscribeAsync(xxx);
   subscriptions.Add(xxx);
   await underlyingComponentB.SubscribeAsync(xxx);
}
```

The problem is, I need to synchronize the dictionary to make sure the Subscribe and Unsubscribe operations don't overlap in a way where the subscriptions list ends up not accurately representing the state of subscriptions.

Conceptually, I would like something along the lines of:

```
lock(_subscriptionsForconnection)
{
    subscriptions = GetOrAdd();
    await SubscribeA();
    subscriptions.Add();
    await SubscribeB();
}
```

However .net 4.5 does not allow you to have `await` inside of a `lock` for a number of reasons, including that your execution might resume in another context, making it impossible to unlock. (Which means Monitor.Enter/Exit will not work).

Another approach would be to serialize the two underlying component calls and make them run synchronously using the `Wait()` method, but this seems wrong.

It occurs to me that I'm probably thinking about this problem wrong, so I welcome your suggestions.

**Additional Details**
I've abstracted a few details out of my explanation to make it clearer. For those who are wondering.
- I'm developing a component on top of SignalR. `underlyingComponentB.SubscribeAsync` is actually the Groups.Add call.
- `underlyingComponentA.SubscribeAsync` is an external message bus that will drive my component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` as a replacement for `lock`.

Comment: Looking at this now: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx
So would you suggest for me to create a semaphore object per instance of `_subscriptionsForconnection` and `WaitAsync()` on it instead?

Comment: I don't know. You wanted lock semantics and this provides them. Hope it helps.